# Why doesn`t operator<< work successfully?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, ostream

While compiling the below code, I am getting an error:

Expression.h

```
class Expression{
    ...
protected:
    std::ostream Os;
};
```

Expression.c

```
Expression::Expression() : Os(std::cout)
{
    ...
} 

Expression::Expression(std::ofstream &os) : Os(os)
{
    ...
}

Expression::Dump()
{
     Os << "=============================================================" << std::endl;
     Os << "Os:               " << Os << std::endl;
}
```

> error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}')

What is my mistake? What should I do to fix it?

And while giving initial value to parameter like this `Os(std::cout)`, what does it mean?

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What do you expect trying to stream out an `ostream` to do? Especially streaming an `ostream` out to itself?!

Comment: The `operator <<` does work as [documented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2). It looks like you did not read the documentation and did not care enough about the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Consider

> ```
>     Os << "Os:               " << Os << std::endl;
> ```

Let us unpack it into its full functional glory:

```
std::ostream& t1 = Os.operator <<("Os:               ");
std::ostream& t2 = t1.operator <<(Os);                   // << Here
std::ostream& t3 = t2.operator <<(std::endl);
```

The problem is the line marked "Here".  You are streaming an ostream to itself.  This is nonsensical.  What are you trying to do?

If you are trying to output an identifier for the stream, you should use the address:

```
    Os << "Os:               " << &Os << std::endl;
```

If you are trying to output the contents of the stream to stdout, you need to make `Os` be an ostringstream, and then output the string buffer:

```
    std::ostringstream Os;
    ...
    std::stdout << "Os:               " << Os.str() << std::endl;
```

---

Note for the pedantic:  I believe my breakdown of the original line into function calls and initializations is actually identical in this particular case (because there are no temporary objects - only references); in general, the lifetime of temporaries might be subtly different.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because there is no standard `operator<<` that writes an `ostream` to another `ostream`.

Also, `ostream` can't be copy-constructed from another `ostream`, so if you are trying to specify an output `ostream` for `Expression` to write to then your `Os` member needs to be declared as a reference instead.

```
class Expression {
    ...
protected:
    std::ostream &Os;
};
```

```
Expression::Expression() : Os(std::cout)
{
    ...
}

Expression::Expression(std::ofstream &os) : Os(os)
{
    ...
}

Expression::Dump()
{
    Os << "=============================================================" << std::endl;
    Os << "Os: " << SomethingThatIsNotOs << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I disagree with the second sentence. If you define some `std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, std::ostream&)` -which would be bizarre- it is unlikely to make an infinite recursion